# How to display list of Enterprise Wiki Categories?

Tags: wiki, categories

I have an Enterprise Wiki site with wiki category items built in the Metadata Term Store.  I cannot figure out how to display a list of all of the wiki categories that link to a list of wiki pages belonging to that category?

Basically my users want a way to navigate through the wiki pages by category.

Comment: I found a web part that may do it: http://metadatawebpart.codeplex.com/ yet it throws the error: "Error rendering web part: Field with name "Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories" was not found".

I know Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories is the correct field name because if I enter "bogus" as the field name I get a different error: "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields."

Maybe this webpart is the the best way to do this.  How about using a Content Query web part?

Comment: Would it be possible to use the Tag Cloud web part to display the wiki categories?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the MetaDataWebPart that is on CodePlex. I had to fix some small bugs but it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like a grouped-by-category web part of the wiki library work for you?